# How to fix 541 issue for masstransit.rabbitmq(5.3.2),rabbitmq.client(5.1.0) for huge batches of published messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Masstransit.RabbitMQ with my dotnet core application. I am building a framework which will wrap Masstransit and if the need be, will be able to plug and play other service bus in the future.

I am getting error in the following LOC:

```
    TaskUtil.Await(BusControl.Publish<Message<TMessage>>(message, c => { c.Durable = true; }));
```

It is generally working fine. But when I try to publish 50000+ messages, I am getting the following error, after delivering 80% of the messages correctly:

> Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, >initiated by Library, code=541, text="Unexpected Exception", classId=0, >methodId=0, cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the >transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the >remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection >was forcibly closed by the remote host
>     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, >Int32 size)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.InboundFrame.ReadFrom(NetworkBinaryReader reader)
>     at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoopIteration()
>     at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoop()

I am using a singleton to create the connection.
Not sure why the connection fails after a point. 
My goal is to build a reliable framework which will be able to process any number of messages.

I have tried adding heartbeat of 5 seconds and set PublishConfirms as true.It just minimized the TAT for the error to be thrown. Just an FYI, Prefetch is set to 16.  I have checked many users who faced similar issue, but could not find a resolution to this.

```
        return MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(settings.RabbitMQURL), hst =>
            {
                hst.Username(settings.RabbitMQUserName);
                hst.Password(settings.RabbitMQPassword);
                hst.Heartbeat(5);
                hst.PublisherConfirmation = true;
            });


            foreach (Action<IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator, IRabbitMqHost> action in settings.BeforeBuildActions)
            {
                action.Invoke(cfg, host);
            }
        });
```

I expect 100000 messages be published and consumed successfully. But am getting the error midway.

Comment: Seems like your broker is being overrun and killing the connection, or your network is unreliable and killing the connection. I can produce that many messages and more using the benchmarking app (MassTransit-Benchmark) without any issues, so this isn't a MassTransit issue.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Is there a way to check if the broker is being overrun? I dont have much to do about the network quality and reliability. But need a direction to move ahead. Thanks

Comment: "Is there a way to check if the broker is being overrun?" - of course, check the logs and monitor your broker (https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html). Posting what RabbitMQ logs at the time of these exceptions would be very helpful.

Comment: Sure, will do. Many thanks luke